# Does a view exist in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to determine if a specific view name exists from within a controller before rendering the view?

I have a requirement to dynamically determine the name of the view to render. If a view exists with that name then I need to render that view. If there is no view by the custom name then I need to render a default view.

I'd like to do something similar to the following code within my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var name = SomeMethodToGetViewName();

    // The 'ViewExists' method is what I've been unable to find.
    if (ViewExists(name))
    {
        retun View(name);
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just reading the title of this , its seems like a very deep philosophical question.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

```
 private bool ViewExists(string name)
 {
     ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, name, null);
     return (result.View != null);
 }
```

For those looking for a copy/paste extension method:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static bool ViewExists(this Controller controller, string name)
    {
        ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, name, null);
        return (result.View != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably better.  I wasn't aware there was a FindView method off of the ViewEngines collection itself.

Comment: But how to check if the view exists for other controller?

Comment: Kind of an aside: one of our engineers (since moved on) built a custom view engine (called MultiTenantViewEngine, so you get a sense of its purpose) that implements FindView to throw a HttpException (404) if it can't find the given view.  Is this good practice?  I have no idea.  But wouldn't be surprised if there are other implementations out there like that.  Since you won't know the inner workings of the view engine as this code executes, you might want to throw a catch { return false; } around this puppy, just to be safe.

Comment: @SOReader , i hvnt tested but , IController controller = new HomeController(); and then controller.ControllerContext will give the thing which you can pass to findview methods.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It helped me in another problem. I needed to check if my view is partial or not and as all my partials' name starts with underline now I can work with my solution checking if "result.View != null"

Comment: Where is `ViewEngines` now in aspnet6?

Comment: ICompositeViewEngine can be injected.

Answer (score 20):

What about trying something like the following assuming you are using only one view engine:

```
bool viewExists = ViewEngines.Engines[0].FindView(ControllerContext, "ViewName", "MasterName", false) != null;
```

Comment: looks like this one was posted 3 minutes before the accepted answer and yet no love?!  +1 from me.

Answer (score 8):

Here's another [not necessarily recommended] way of doing it

```
 try
 {
     @Html.Partial("Category/SearchPanel/" + Model.CategoryKey)
 }
 catch (InvalidOperationException) { }
```

Comment: this is for testing existance of a partial view within a .cshtml file. it isn't really an answer for this question, but another question that links here was incorrectly closed so I'm leaving my answer here

Comment: This was actually spot on for my use, since I was looking for a way to use a culture specific partial view. So i just called this with the culture specific view name, and then called the default view inside the catch. And I was doing this in a utility function, so I had no access to the `ControllerContext` as the `FindView` method needs.

Answer (score 5):

In asp.net core 2.x and aspnet6 the `ViewEngines` property no longer exists so we have to use the `ICompositeViewEngine` service. This a variant of the accepted answer using dependency injection:

```
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    private readonly IViewEngine _viewEngine;

    public DemoController(ICompositeViewEngine viewEngine)
    {
        _viewEngine = viewEngine;
    }

    private bool ViewExists(string name)
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewEngineResult = _viewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext, name, true);
        return viewEngineResult?.View != null;
    }

    public ActionResult Index() ...
}
```

For the curious: The base interface `IViewEngine` is not registered as a service so we must inject `ICompositeViewEngine` instead. The `FindView()` method however is provided by `IViewEngine` so the member variable may use the base interface.

Comment: This also works in aspnet6.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to re-use this across multiple controller actions, building on the solution given by Dave, you can define a custom view result as follows:

```
public class CustomViewResult : ViewResult
{
    protected override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext context)
    {
        string name = SomeMethodToGetViewName();

        ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(context, name, null);

        if (result.View != null)
        {
            return result;
        }

        return base.FindView(context);
    }

    ...
}
```

Then in your action simply return an instance of your custom view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    return new CustomViewResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext, "View Name").View != null
```

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in Razor for Core 2.2 etc. Note that the call is "GetView", not "Find View)

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines
@inject ICompositeViewEngine Engine
...
@if (Engine.GetView(scriptName, scriptName, isMainPage: false).Success) 
{
    @await Html.PartialAsync(scriptName)
}
```