# ASP.NET MVC 3 - render an optional partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a View Exist in Asp.Net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946990/does-a-view-exist-in-asp-net-mvc)

Is there any way to render a partial view only if it exists? Sort of like the capability RenderSection has...

**EDIT: Duplicate of [Does a View Exist in Asp.Net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946990/does-a-view-exist-in-asp-net-mvc/947086#947086), please vote to close this.**

Comment: Do you mean if the viewdata for that partial exists or is this a situation where you try to calculate the name of a partial view from some formula?

Comment: The "duplicate" is about finding out if a view exists from within a controller. However, ControllerContext does not seem to be available in the View, where I'd like to render a partial view only if it exists.

Comment: nevermind, I found it in `ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext`

Comment: this is NOT a duplicate. the referenced question wants to determine whether or not a full View exists before rendering it. this question asks about partial views which is different