# Minimal way to handle static content routes/controllers/views from data driven menus?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, routes

I have a ListItem class that is used to represent menu items in my application:

```
 public class ListItem : Entity
{
    public virtual List List { get; set; }
    public virtual ListItem ParentItem { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ListItem> ChildItems { get; set; }

    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

I use this data to construct the routes for the application, but I was wondering if there was a clean way to handle controller/views for static content? Basically any page that doesn't use any data but just views. Right now I have one controller called StaticContentController, which contains a unique action for each static page that returns the appropriate view like so:

```
public class StaticContentController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Books()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Books/Index.cshtml");
    }

    public ActionResult BookCategories()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Books/Categories.cshtml");
    }

    public ActionResult BookCategoriesSearch()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Books/Categories/Search.cshtml");
    }
}
```

Is there some way I could minimize this so I don't have to have so many controllers/actions for static content? It seems like when creating my ListItem data I could set the Controller to a specific controller that handles static content, like I have done, but is there anyway to use one function to calculate what View to return? It seems like I still need separate actions otherwise I won't know what page the user was trying to get to.

The ListItem.Url contains the full URL path from the application root used in creating the route. The location of the View in the project would correspond to the URL location to keep the organization structure parallel.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Edit: My Route registration looks like so:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Shared/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute("Access Denied", "AccessDenied", new { controller = "Shared", action = "AccessDenied", area = "" });
        List<ListItem> listItems = EntityServiceFactory.GetService<ListItemService>().GetAllListItmes();
        foreach (ListItem item in listItems.Where(item => item.Text != null && item.Url != null && item.Controller != null).OrderBy(x => x.Url))
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(item.Text + listItems.FindIndex(x => x == item), item.Url.StartsWith("/") ? item.Url.Remove(0, 1) : item.Url, new { controller = item.Controller, action = item.Action ?? "index" });
        }

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );


    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a single Action with one parameter (the View name) which will return all the static pages

```
public class StaticContentController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Page(string viewName)
    {
        return View(viewName);
    }
}
```

You will also need to create a custom route for serving these views, for example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "StaticContent",                                      // Route name
    "page/{viewName}",                                    // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "StaticContent", action = "Page" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

I see in your example that you specify different folders for your views. This solution will force you to put all static views in the Views folder of the StaticContentController.

If you must have custom folder structure, then you can change the route to accept `/` by adding `*` to the `{viewName}` like this `{*viewname}`. Now you can use this route: `/page/Books/Categories`. In the `viewName` input parameter you will receive `"Books/Categories"` which you can then return it as you like: `return View(string.Format("~/Views/{0}.cshtml", viewName));`

**UPDATE (Avoiding the `page/` prefix)**

The idea is to have a custom constraint to check whether or not a file exists. Every file that exists for a given URL will be treated as static page.

```
public class StaticPageConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        string viewPath = httpContext.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Views/{0}.cshtml", values[parameterName]));

        return File.Exists(viewPath);
    }
}
```

Update the route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "StaticContent",                                       // Route name
    "{*viewName}",                                         // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "StaticContent", action = "Page" }, // Parameter defaults
    new { viewName = new StaticPageConstraint() }          // Custom route constraint
);
```

Update the action:

```
public ActionResult Page(string viewName)
{
    return View(string.Format("~/Views/{0}.cshtml", viewName));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to get this to work without doing the `page/` part? I would like to have not have that being prefixed on all my URLs. Another question I have (and this may just be a design one) is how could I calculate to return the view depending on whether it should return an index.cshtml view or not? What I mean is that route `Books/Categories` could point to `~/Vews/Books/Categories.cshtml` or it may point to `~/Viws/Books/Categories/Index.cshtml` which depends on if an item has any child items or not. Can I just check if it exists then return the one that exists?

Comment: I think it may not be possible to do this without the `page/` prefix while still having the default route work, is that correct? I need the default route to still work for non static content. I've updated my post to include my route registration. As you can see, I am already checking to see if the action is null in the ListItem and if so set it to Index, but with your suggested method, this would no longer be possible.

Comment: **About the page prefix:** It is possible by specifying a route constraint as a regular expression or by building your own custom route constraint. But this will significantly complicate things and will limit your options of possible URLs. **About the index view:** Do you really needs this? I thought that you need a solution for few static pages. If you have this many pages then it is probably a better idea to implement CMS like features and keep your pages in the database.

Comment: **Page Prefix:** Can you provide an example, I am not sure what you mean? **Index View**: There are quite a few static pages, and we are on the way to implementing a full CMS solution, but we're kind of in transition now and it won't be a while until we can complete that feature set. However, I found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946990/does-a-view-exist-in-asp-net-mvc which should cover that problem fine.

Comment: I have **updated** my answer. The question that u posted will solve the problem in the controller, but in the route constraint class I didn't manage to get the controller context. For that reason I went with the classic File class. You can extend this logic to check for the Index view.