# Check if (partial) view exists from HtmlHelperMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know if it's possible to check if a partial view exists from within an HtmlHelperExtension?

I know it's possible from a controller using the following:

```
 private bool ViewExists(string name)
 {
     ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, name, null);
     return (result.View != null);
 }
```

Source: [Does a View Exist in Asp.Net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946990/does-a-view-exist-in-asp-net-mvc)

But you can't do the above in a helper, as you don't have access to the controller context. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> But you can't do the above in a helper, as you don't have access to the controller context.

Oh yes, you do have access:

```
public static HtmlString MyHelper(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    var controllerContext = html.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext;
    var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controllerContext, name, null);
    ...
}
```

Comment: what about when your partialview sits inside another custom sub folder within the Shared folder! it won't find it then :(

Comment: A Razor page app (with Core 2.2) doesn't seem to have a `ControllerContext`. Do you know if it can be done in some other way?

Comment: I wrote answer for  Aspnet core 3.x, 5x, you can check.

Answer (score 10):

For completeness, the way to find a partial view, is actually as follows.

```
public static HtmlString MyHelper(this HtmlHelper html)
{
     var controllerContext = html.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext;
     ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, name);
     ...
}
```

And be sure to include the extension of the view; either cshtml for razor or aspx for webforms view engines.

Comment: this also won't work when your partial views sit within a custom sub folder inside the Shared folder.

Comment: @Ciwan you need to add path for subfolder, like: ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, "subfolderpath/" + name);

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Asp.Net Core (Mvc) you can check if "View" exists in your HtmlHelper Extension like this:

```
    public static IHtmlContent PartialOzz<TModel>(IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, partialViewName)
    {
        var requestServices = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices;
        var viewEngine = requestServices.GetService<ICompositeViewEngine>();

        var viewEngineResult = viewEngine.GetView(htmlHelper.ViewContext.ExecutingFilePath, partialViewName, isMainPage: false);
        if (viewEngineResult.Success)
            return htmlHelper.PartialAsync(partialViewName, me.Model).Result;

        viewEngineResult = viewEngine.FindView(htmlHelper.ViewContext, partialViewName, isMainPage: false);
        if (viewEngineResult.Success)
            return htmlHelper.PartialAsync(partialViewName, me.Model).Result;

        
        return new HtmlString($"### {partialViewName} Not Found ###");
     }
```