# Find if a view exists using the controller and view names?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need help finding how to check if a view exists using only its view and controller name. I have examples like:

```
ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, null);
```

But them I need the ControllerContext. How can I do it using the Controller name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if (partial) view exists from HtmlHelperMethod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211975/check-if-partial-view-exists-from-htmlhelpermethod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Yes, check out google or try the search on SO. It works!

Darin Dimitrov gave a good answer here: [Check if (partial) view exists from HtmlHelperMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211975/check-if-partial-view-exists-from-htmlhelpermethod)

From his answer:

```
public static HtmlString MyHelper(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    var controllerContext = html.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext;
    var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controllerContext, name, null);
    ...
}
```