# How to tell ASP.NET Core view exists from controller?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Sometimes a controller needs to check if a view exists so that it can take some action if it doesn't?

I've seen similar questions like this one [Does a view exist in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946990/does-a-view-exist-in-asp-net-mvc) for prior versions of asp.net mvc but such approaches don't work for ASP.NET Core.  I have been unable to locate any documentation on how to do it with ASP.NET Core from inside the controller.

Given the following:

```
string viewLoc= "~/views/some-folder/some-file.cshtml";
```

How can the controller determine if the view exists?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem in **Asp.Net Core** 1.0. Use ICompositeViewEngine. This below is an example.

```
private readonly ICompositeViewEngine _compositeViewEngine;

public YourController(ICompositeViewEngine compositeViewEngine)
{
    _compositeViewEngine = compositeViewEngine;
}
```

And then in your Action:

```
[Route("/location/{name}")]
public IActionResult Location(string name)
{
    var viewName = $"~/Views/Location/{name}.cshtml";
    var result = _compositeViewEngine.GetView("", viewName, false);

    if (result.Success) return View(viewName);

    // or do whatever you want
    return NotFound();
}
```

Comment: THIS answer should be the accepted answer starting in Asp.Net Core 3.0 where precompiled views are the default. While a `File.Exists` check will work in dev still, once the website is published, the views won't be there so a `File.Exists` will fail even if the view is present as a precompiled view. `compositeViewEngine.GetView` will see the precompiled view if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it's a bad design when View not exist on runtime - but probably I don't understand the case.

However answering your question:
I don't know any specific method to do this, but... View is a file, so you can just check if file exist on disk ?

For example:

- `System.IO.File.Exists(@"Views\Home\Index.cshtml");`
- `System.IO.File.Exists(@".\Views\Home\Index.cshtml");`

Do not use `~` in this case, just `Views\` or `.\Views\`

Comment: I came up with a similar approach as well but used an absolute path that was achieved by appending `IHostingEnvironment` `ContentRootPath` but it felt a bit dirty to me since I could see that I can inject `IRazorViewEngine` into the controller and it has a `FindView` method.  But I could never getit to reutrn `ViewEngineResult.Success` as true.  So in the end I did resort to using System.IO.FIle.Exists.

Comment: Please note that `IApplicationEnvironment` and `IRuntimeEnvironment` was removed in RC2 and is accessible statically via `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices.Default`, more info: https://github.com/aspnet/PlatformAbstractions/issues/37

Comment: Good tip.  In my case I used `IHostingEnvironment` to get the `ContentRootPath`.   `IHostingEnvironment` is `Controller` injectable in RC2.

Comment: a... sorry, I have read this too quick... `IHostingEnvironment` is not the same like as `IApplicationEnvironment` ;)

Comment: This breaks if the views are precompiled and the file does not exist on disk.

Comment: Yes, it was written (and tested) at 2016 on ASP.NET Core v1 ;)