# In asp.net-mvc what is the faster way to check if a partial view exists from Site.Master file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have code in my Site.Master file that looks like this:

```
<% var menuName = StaticHelper.GetSiteMenuName(); %>
<%Html.RenderPartial("Menu" + menuName .ToUpper()); %>
```

So if your menu name is "NewYork", it will look for a partial view called "MenuNewYork".

This works fine but in some cases now I don't have menu setup so i wanted to have it default to a default menu.  I want something like this:

```
<% var menuName = StaticHelper.GetSiteMenuName(); %>
<% if (PartialViewExists("Menu" + menuName) { %>
      <%Html.RenderPartial("Menu" + menuName .ToUpper()); %>
<% }else { %>
      <%Html.RenderPartial("MenuDEFAULT"); %>
<% } %>
```

### Update

I found a solution here

```
public static bool DoesPartialViewExist(this HtmlHelper html, string partialViewName)
{
    var controllerContext = html.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext;
    ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName);
    return (result.View != null);
}
```

I am just trying to see if there is a faster solution as I very conscious of any performance hit that this would take given this code would run on every single page load given its inside the site.master file.

Comment: How about this http://stackoverflow.com/a/947086/4868839

Comment: You can determine the filename at backend.Use System.IO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Update

After reviewing the source code of MVC on Githup the internals are already caching the paths found when getting views and partial views, which would make my original suggestion premature optimization.

That would mean that the answer you found and referenced...

```
public static bool DoesPartialViewExist(this HtmlHelper html, string partialViewName) {
    var controllerContext = html.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext;
    var viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName);
    return (viewEngineResult.View != null);
}
```

is already optimized.

---

### Original

You can cache the value for future lookups to try and improve performance for multiple requests.

```
static IDictionary<string, bool> partialViewCache = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
public static bool DoesPartialViewExist(this HtmlHelper html, string partialViewName) {
    bool value = false;
    if (partialViewCache.TryGetValue(partialViewName, out value)) {
        var controllerContext = html.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext;
        ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName);
        value = result.View != null;
        partialViewCache[partialViewName] = value;
    }
    return value;
}
```

In the above a static field is used to hold on to the value but the method could just as easily used another caching mechanism. ie MemeoryCache, IMemoryCache, etc, depending on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way, if you know the full path of the file, is to check if the file exist using System.IO

```
string curView = @"c:\YourSite\Views\whatever.cshtml";
if (File.Exists(curView))
{
  //Continue to view
}
```

But I think the better approach will be what you stated.
You can combine your check with some cache storage so it will almost have no effect on runtime.