# Unit testing if methods find and return a view in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET and I'm refactoring some functionalities in my MVC-structured ASP.NET application into area's. This has already lead to controller-methods not able to find their views anymore, which results in the following page:

[image]

To test if all controllers can find their views, I'd like to write some automated unit tests for this.

I have came up with the following:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AboutTest()
{
    var controller = new HomeController();
    var result = controller.About() as ViewResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

which tests the About-method in the following code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View("~/Views/SomeFolder/Contact.cshtml");
    }
}
```

But even when the HomeControllers About-method can not find a view, this assert succeeds, so this does not work for me.

I have found [a solution online](https://stackoverflow.com/a/947086/5437768) to use use ViewEngine.FindView() here. I don't think I can use this, since in some controllers the views are referenced by a hardcoded string (see the contact method in the example controller above) instead of just returning the default view (simularly named as its method). The ViewEngine.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, "about", "about"); will then fail, but the controller-method would not.

[Another solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/unit-testing/creating-unit-tests-for-asp-net-mvc-applications-cs#testing-the-view-returned-by-a-controller) states to use Assert.IsEqual() and check if the result.ViewName is equal to a hardcoded string (for example: "About"). Since I do not set or know the title of the views I'm expecting to get returned, this would not be a solution either.

(How) would I be able to test my application for this?

Comment: I think it won't be null, because you _do_ get a response, it just happens to be an error page. If the HTTP response is correctly set (e.g. 404) by the application then you could use that, but there's a good chance it won't be.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't check for null, it will return a ViewResult even when it doesn't render.

To test whether it actually renders use `AssertViewRendered` from [mvccontrib](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mvccontrib).

```
[TestMethod]
public void AboutTest()
{
    var controller = new HomeController();
    var result = controller.About().AssertViewRendered();
}
```

You can even check for a specific view like so:

```
result.AssertViewRendered().ForView(MVC.Your.Views.AboutView);
```

Or supply data like so:

```
controller.page().AssertViewRendered().ForView("page").WithViewData<SomeModel>();
```

For an interactive tutorial with lots of pictures I can recommend: http://toreaurstad.blogspot.nl/2011/09/adventures-with-mvccontrib-testhelper.html

**Edit:**

You might also check out [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) to test your entire app (incl. rendering of 200 routes).