# How to check if a view exist in shared folder in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to know view exists in ASP.NET Core?

I'm searching for a pseudo-code like this:

```
@if (Exists("/Views/Shared/SomeView.cshtml"))
{
    Html.Partial("/Views/Shared/SomeView.cshtml"))
}
```

Comment: Well a .cshtml file is a file. And .NET has this whole namespace for working with files called System.IO.

Comment: Did you try this ? if (System.IO.File.Exists("~/Views/Shared/SomeView.cshtml")) or this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946990/does-a-view-exist-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @mason, for the sake of DevOps, in local machines we develop on local IIS. That means that our `AppContext.BaseDirectory` is `\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1` in development, and `\` in production. This causes errors. And while it can be solved by a simple flag, it doesn't seem to be a clean method.

Comment: @EsatARSLAN, I can't find `ViewEngine` in ASP.NET Core MVC.

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli So? All that means is you need to handle a relative path. [This blog post](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/302/server-mappath-equivalent-in-asp-net-core) explains how to get certain directories in your app. That leaves you with something like `File.Exists(Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "Views", "Shared", "SomeView.cshtml"));`

Comment: @mason, another problem is that file-system method doesn't work with embedded views.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [FindView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewengines.iviewengine.findview?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ViewEngines_IViewEngine_FindView_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ActionContext_System_String_System_Boolean_) for this. Inside of a view, you can use dependency injection to get an instance of `ICompositeViewEngine`, which is registered for you when adding the MVC services. Using this instance, it's possible to determine whether or not the view exists using something like the following:

```
@inject ICompositeViewEngine Engine

@if (Engine.FindView(ViewContext, "SomeView", isMainPage: false).Success)
{
    @Html.Partial("SomeView");
}
```

If you specifically want to check whether or not the View exists in a *specific* folder (e.g. Shared in your example), you can use `GetView`:

```
@if (Engine.GetView(null, "Views/Shared/SomeView.cshtml", isMainPage: false).Success)
```

Comment: Does it work for embedded views too? Because I tested and I didn't get the result.

Comment: I've published the project and run it with precompiled views and it works correctly. What do you mean by *embedded views* here? Getting the path right in the code I've shown proved to be a bit fiddly - Can you describe the file-system layout you're using?

Comment: I'm using `<EmbeddedResource Include="Views\**\*.cshtml" />` to embed all of my module views into the compiled dll, and to use that dll across many projects.